# How do I check if this person has already used a command on discord?

Tags: discord.py

so I am making a card game on discord and I want to make sure that one person can't join the game multiple times.

```py
    if message.content == "$join":
        players.append(message.author)
```

Is it possible to find out the name of the person who used $join, and remove him from a list so that he can't join again

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the `players` list is a list of current playing users, you can simply check if the user is already in it

```py
if message.content == "$join":
    if message.author in players:
        await message.channel.send("You already joined the game")
    else:
        players.append(message.author)
```